# If a discrete random variable is independent to other two discrete random variable, is it independent to the sum?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, independence, moments

Suppose X,Y,Z are discrete random variables and X is independent to both Y and Z.
Is X independent to Y + Z?

I know this is not necessarily true but I am struggling to find a counterexample.

It would really be appreciated if anyone could kindly find a counterexample.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider two independent coin tosses, and the following definitions:

- Let $X = 1$ if first toss is Heads
- Let $Y = 1$ if second toss is Heads
- Let $Z = 1$ if only one toss is Heads

You'll find that these events are pairwise independent. Yet, the following inequality remains $$0=P(X=1|Y+Z=2)\neq P(X=1)=1/2$$
which is a counter-example for independence assertion.